# Is there a difference between magnetic moment and monopole moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles, dipole-moment

I have stumbled upon the following formulation:

> For a magnetic pole located at $X=Y=Z=0$ with monopole moment $g=\text{constant}$, the magnetic 3-vector is given by: $\mathbf{B} = \frac{g}{r^3}(X,Y,Z)$, where $r = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}$.

I have never seen the use of term "monopole moment" and so was wondering if it is the same as magnetic moment that can be obtained through far-field expansion of the magnetic potential.

Wanted to find out if anyone else stumbled upon "monopole moment" before and if I am right to assume that it is the same as the "magnetic moment"?

Comment: Reference? It sounds like this is more about "magnetic pole strength", "magnetic charge", which is useful in engineering calculations. It is not magnetic moment, which is generally understood as a dipole.

Comment: Also, magnetic monopoles strictly do not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The "monopole moment" is the magnetic analogue of electric charge: the strength of the source of magnetic field. In nature, objects with a magnetic monopole moment have not been observed, though they are predicted by some Grand Unified Theories.

"Magnetic moment" refers to magnetic *dipole* moment, which is not the same as monopole moment.

In general, a monopole moment is the leading term in a [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion); the dipole moment is the second-order term. Quadrupole, octupole and higher moments can also be defined analogously.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation!

Comment: @Pieter sorry, typo fixed